# Cumulative sum of a row containing percentage value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am quite novice to google appscript, and I am stuck with a problem which I couldn't find a solution for quite sometime now.

Using appscript, I am trying to do a cumulative sum of values which are currently in % format(using   .setNumberFormat("0.00%;(0.00)%")). See below screenshot:

[image: how the output should look like]

1. col E: has the calculated values(using appscript; using
   .setNumberFormat("0.00%;(0.00)%"))
2. col F: thats the output i need to achieve using appscript
3. col G: i have shown what the calculation is for the out i am trying to achieve in col F, just to make sure i am not 
     confusing

The code I currently have
`

```
function TTMrankAnalysis() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var yourNewSheet = ss.getSheetByName("TTM Rank Analysis");
    var lr = yourNewSheet.getLastRow();
    var lc = yourNewSheet.getLastColumn();

    var cogsTotal = ss.getSheetByName("TTM_Report_Paste").getRange(6, 2).getValue(); //total COGS
      Logger.log(cogsTotal);

    var cogsValuesRange = yourNewSheet.getRange(2,3,lr-1).getValues(); //cogs range
      Logger.log(cogsValuesRange);

        for(var i=0; i<cogsValuesRange.length; i++){

          var d = cogsValuesRange[i];
          var percentCogs = d/cogsTotal
          Logger.log(percentCogs);

          var cogsPasteRange = yourNewSheet.getRange(i+2, lc-1)
          var cogsPercentagePaste = cogsPasteRange.setValue(percentCogs); //sets %cogs from high to low
          cogsPercentagePaste.setNumberFormat("0.00%;(0.00)%");
         };

        yourNewSheet.getRange(2,3,lr-1).setNumberFormat("$#,##0.00;$(#,##0.00)"); //sets $$$ symbol for shipped cogs

        //for cumulative % of COGS
      var cogsPercentageValues = yourNewSheet.getRange(2, lc-1, lr-1).getValues();  
      Logger.log(cogsPercentageValues);

        var sum = 0;
        for (var i=0;i<cogsPercentageValues.length; i++) {

         sum+=cogsPercentageValues[i];
        Logger.log(sum);

        var cumulativeCogsPasteRange = yourNewSheet.getRange(i+2, lc)
          var cumulativeCogsPercentagePaste = cumulativeCogsPasteRange.setValue(percentCogs); //sets %cogs from high to low

        };
}
```

Please note, I have included the code which I use to achieve the values present in Col E, just to make sure the flow is not broken.

Comment: Small correction to the  title of the question: its NOT row, but **COLUMN**

Comment: Please describe the problem. Are you getting an error message or the wrong result? Also add some sample input data and the expected result.

Comment: @Rubén 
the sample input and output that i am trying to achieve is shown above in my question(see screenshot and it explanation underneath).

The problem is, i am unable to achieve the output i desire, infact the code mentioned above(the second part of it - "//for cumulative % of COGS"), is where i am having trouble. The code in that part above, is supposed to cumulatively sum the data already achieved in colG using appscript(first part of above code). Thanks for your response and looking forward to hearing your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
function sumEF() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getRange('E1:F5');
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
    if(i==0){
      vA[i][1]=vA[i][0];
    }else{
      vA[i][1]=vA[i-1][1]+vA[i][0];
    }
  }
  rg.setValues(vA);
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks @cooper!
Just that, i had to add a small bit to the code - rg1.setValues(vA).setNumberFormat("0.00%;(0.00)%"). because the output was something like - 0.12456, 0.5648, etc.. after apply the "setNumberFormat", i was able to achieve what i wanted to. Appreciate your help once again!